SQL Server 2016 DB_CHAINING with Views
Over night it seems that we've started having users that can no longer read views in our databases where the target table is in another database. I've exhausted everything I can find so far to find the reason behind this, but I've simply gotten stuck now and would require some assistance.
In order for views to work like this, where the end user does not have explicit grants to SELECT on both databases, the option to have DB_CHAINING needs to be on. This is on for all the databases in question. Another prerequisite is to have the same database owner, which is also checked and verified to still be the case. The end users must also have connect grants to the target database where the table is, which they also do.
This is the query that checks the owner of the databases, and the DB_CHAINING option:
SELECT 
    name, 
    suser_sname(owner_sid) AS owner_name,
    is_db_chaining_on,owner_sid,
    owner_sid
FROM 
    sys.databases
WHERE 
    name IN ('TargetDB', 'ViewDB');

I've also ensured that there is no explicit grants denying access, which has not changed since yesterday and the response is still no.
With above in mind, I cannot figure out what is wrong.
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - 13.0.5893.48

Did you introduce dynamic sql somewhere? It nullifies db chaining

We do have dynamic SQL queries yes, but nothing related to this.

Can you post a sample query and exact error

The sample query is just an select top 1 from the view, and the view itself is just an select * from the table in the target db. No logic that will impact anything really. The error is "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Test_table', database 'Warehouse', schema 'dbo'." So, nothing that tells us anything else than the fact that something is off with the chaining.

"Something changed overnight". Can you restore a version of the databases somewhere else, verify they're working, and diff them with the live databases?

In this case "Something changed over night" is an assumption based on the fact that this error did not appear before, and it's been running for years. I am unable to restore the database to a previous version without disrupting production quite a bit - and I would argue that finding the error is X amounts more important than simply restoring it and hoping it won't happen again. Restore is last resort, not first.

To be clear, there was no intentional change made yesterday.

Can you see when the server was last restarted? And if error log displays something interesting

Server was rebooted by first line support at 9:50 today, before that was about 45 hours ago now. There is nothing that pops up in the error log that indicates any issue.

The restore comment was a) not to restore to production, just restore somewhere, and b) then compare to the live version in order to spot what has changed. That assuming you don't version control your database.

I assume you have checked that the objects all have the same owners as well? The ownership of objects must be the same throughout. The objects must be owned by the USER linked to the LOGIN that owns the database(s).

@ThomA please read the question. As mentioned there, it's the same.

I checked the question a couple of times before I commented, but I've reread the question again, however, I can't see you state anywhere that the objects have the same owners, @Ph1reman , only the databases. If I have missed that bit, could you quote in the comments please?

You're correct, I misunderstood. My bad. If it brings you joy, I'd be very happy for you to suggest this as a fix. Because the problem was technically not ownership problems on the objects, but the schemas. It's been fixed and it now works!

@DaleK Missed your note, sorry. In this case the log did not pick up the changes, as it was done automatically during a change of a database owner which was reverted. When reverted, the underlaying schema did not get reverted, hence the issue persisted. And no, no version control on database level. Objects are tracked, but that is it. This is a legacy server.

It's funny you wrote that nothing changed BESIDES a huge change

You are correct, let me rephrase - No communicated change had happened. This was a mistake by an DBA that failed to revert a test.

The schema that owned the objects was not the same as the DB_OWNER. The issue was resolved by sorting this. The reason why this was not available in the logs was that the change of DB_OWNER was done with the SP for it, and it did not log the schema owner change. When reverting it, only the DB_OWNER was reverted.
Credit to @Thom A for asking the right question.
